# The meaning of the Roles in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

Today I have a question to make regarding the `Roles`.

Just because I’m confused around this issue I’d like to ask the following questions, and please I would like to receive clear and easy understandable answers. Not deep analyze.

1. What is the `Roles` for a programmer?
2. What is the role of the `Schemas owned by this…` which related with them?
3. What is the meaning and the use for `securables` in `Roles`
4. Why we add users to a `Role`?
5. How we may handle the `Roles` in conjunction with to the users, inside of a project?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles are basically like a "group" for granting permissions.  There are built-in roles `public`, `sysadmin`, `dbcreator`, etc. but you can also create your own roles.  For example, if you have a project called "secretary" or something, you could create a secretary role, and then add users to the role so that you can grant the same permissions to everyone in the role.

The securables are basically any permissions that are granted to that role.  You add users to a role so that they will have the same permissions that are granted to the role.  Everyone in the "secretary" role would have the same permissions (in addition to whatever individual permissions they may have).  Hope that helps.

Comment: As far I have seen the Securables are Procedures or views... what the permissions have to do with them...

Comment: In order to execute a procedure, you must have `EXECUTE` permissions on that procedure.  Likewise, you must have `SELECT` permissions on a table or view to select rows.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that is clear... thank you. Now I'm getting the opportunity to say what I'm planning to do... with hope to help in answers. I have a number of pages... and a huge number of users... every user has its own code which groupies them in relation to certain pages.. are the Roles suitable for this action?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that is a perfect example of when roles can be useful.  I'm not sure exactly what you mean by pages and grouping users in relation to certain pages, but it does sound like roles should be useful.

Comment: When I say pages I mean Web.Pages in my web application (like a chat or something) and when I say Grouping I mean when a number of users have the same code (09.01.01).. In this case I have to assign those web.pages to the securables!!

Comment: Okay, I think I see.  Just remember, that the roles/securables are permissions on the underlying database.  So make sure to set up the roles accordingly.

Comment: @LefterisGkinis Procedures and views are not the only securables; there is a list of all of them at [MSDN:Securables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190401.aspx). Note that this includes user-defined table types, for which you would use something like `GRANT EXECUTE ON TYPE::[dbo].[userDefinedTable] TO [UserName]` as you can't do that in SSMS (AFAIK).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes Andrew but either of way what I have in my hands is... A) A User (which is not in database, but is only in the application) with a unique code(special number) and B) A number of web.Pages on which some of the user has to have access and some not have access... That's why I was thinking to use the Roles... I don't know if that is right or wrong...

Comment: @AndrewMorton Or I have to create my own relation between those Users and there relative web.pages???

Comment: @LefterisGkinis I only wanted to alert you to the fact that it is not only procedures and views which are securables. If you have further questions on SQL Server, you might want to ask in the more appropriate forum [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).